# Log4J2 with Websphere 8.5

Tags: websphere, log4j2, websphere-8

I am trying to do a log4j migration for a legacy application. I made the changes to the configuration files and tested it locally with Tomcat, where the logs were displayed correctly. However when I deploy on WAS, the logging stops.
I checked a lot of pages about the necessary dependencies and the possible problems, but now I feel I'm stuck. Here is what I already tried:

- Added the log4j jars manually to the lib/ext directory in WAS (together with commons-logging, I read an article where it helped, although all these jar-s were already present in the ear)
- Double checked, that the configuration file is on the classpath and that it's syntax is correct
- Added logj42-web dependency
- Added the necessary filters in web.xml (Spring version is 3.8, so also the config listener with the config name context-param)
- Checked classloader in WAS - it's parent first

Am I missing something?

Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

WAS includes its own commons-logging API (that does not utilize Log4j), so bringing your own logger requires a bit of extra class-loader-related config. Typically, that would go something like this:

1. Put your commons-logging and log4j jars, along with your logging properties files, in some directory (not WAS_HOME/lib/ext) readable by the user running the server.
2. Create a shared library on the server, with that directory as its class path, and select the "use an isolated class loader" option. Associate that shared library with your application or web module.

Ideally, that should be it. Isolated shared libraries search themselves before delegating to the server's loaders, so your application will "see" the commons-logging/log4j classes in the shared library instead of in the server, and likewise, it should pick up the configuration files from that directory instead of the ones found in the server.

You can also accomplish this same basic thing by leaving all the logging stuff in your WAR or EAR and setting its class loader to parent-last (which causes the class loader to search locally before delegating to the server-level loaders), but that is a bit riskier configuration - if your application includes APIs that are also provided by the server, parent-last class loading increases the possibility of ClassCastExceptions or LinkageErrors.